# Adicionando linhas de uma matriz em uma list view Window Form

Tags: c#, winforms

estou fazendo um projeto para resolver o binômio de newton, essa parte tá fácil consegui resolver o problema no console do jeito que eu queria, agora estou migrando para Windows Form e estou com um problema para imprimir o triangulo de pascal em uma listbox.
Quero imprimir neste formado

[1]

[1][1]

[1][2][1]

[1][3][3][1]

[1][4][6][4][1]

Mas não consigo fazer assim na list box, ele acaba imprimindo um em cima do outro.

[1]

[1]

[1]

[1]

[2]

[1]
O código que usei para fazer no console.

```
int n;
   Console.WriteLine("Digite o valor de  N");
                n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                n = n + 1;
                matriz_triangulo = new int[n, n];
  Console.WriteLine("Digite o valor de  N");
                n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                n = n + 1;
                matriz_triangulo = new int[n, n];



            for (int linha = 0; linha < n; linha++)
            {
                for (int coluna = 0; coluna < n; coluna++)
                {
                    if (linha == coluna || coluna == 0)
                    {
                        matriz_triangulo[linha, coluna] = 1;
                    }
                    else if (linha != 0 && coluna != 0)
                    {
                        matriz_triangulo[linha, coluna] = matriz_triangulo[linha - 1, coluna - 1] + matriz_triangulo[linha - 1, coluna];
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int linha = 0; linha < n; linha++)
            {
                for (int coluna = 0; coluna < n; coluna++)
                {
                    if (matriz_triangulo[linha, coluna] != 0 && matriz_triangulo[linha, coluna] != 0)
                        Console.Write("[" + matriz_triangulo[linha, coluna] + "] ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solução

```
for (int linha = 0; linha < n; linha++)
            {
                string linhaListBox = "";
                for (int coluna = 0; coluna < n; coluna++)
                {
                    if (triangulo_pascal[linha, coluna] != 0 && triangulo_pascal[linha, coluna] != 0)
                        linhaListBox += "[" + triangulo_pascal[linha, coluna] + "] ";
                }
                lbx_trianguloPascal.Items.Add(linhaListBox);
            }
```